# Create Calculate Measures in SSAS

Tags: ssas, mdx, cube, measure

Please consider this scenarios:

I have a cube with one `Fact` table and one measure called `SalesAmount` . Now I want to create a measure based on these 2 `Select`s:

`Select 1`:

```
Select [Measures].[SalesAmount]
From MyCube
Where [Product].[Color].[Gray]
```

and `Select 2`:

```
Select [Measures].[SalesAmount]
From MyCube
Where [Dates].[Calendar Year].&[2015]
```

The problem is in `Add Calculate Member` there is a box for simple formula. How can I create a measure for `Select 1` + `Select 2`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure where are you looking at this Add Calculate Member option, but you could try something like this (Adventure Works database).

```
with member measures.[MyMeasure1]
as
([Measures].[Internet Sales Amount], [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].&[2006])

member measures.[MyMeasure2]
as
([Measures].[Internet Sales Amount], [Product].[Color].&[Grey])

member measures.[MyMeasure12]
as
measures.[MyMeasure1] + measures.[MyMeasure2]

select {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount], measures.[MyMeasure1], measures.[MyMeasure2] , measures.[MyMeasure12]} on 0
from [Adventure Works]
```

[image]

You can also create those members from Visual Studio Data Tools - in Calculations tab:

[image]